# Proof that trace is independent of representation

Tags: quantum-mechanics, operators, hilbert-space, representation-theory, trace

[image]

$$\begin{align}
\sum_{a'} \langle a'|X|a'\rangle &=\sum_{a',b',b''} \langle a'|b'\rangle \langle b'|X|b''\rangle\langle b''|a'\rangle \\
&=\sum_{b',b''} \langle b''|b'\rangle \langle b'|X|b''\rangle \\
&= \sum_{b'} \langle b'|X|b'\rangle
\end{align}$$

How does step 1 go to step 2? How do $|a'\rangle$ states get cancelled out?

Answer (score 3):

The trick is the following. Write

$$\sum_{a',b,b'} \langle a'|b'\rangle \langle b'|X|b''\rangle\langle b''|a'\rangle = \sum_{b,b'} \langle b'|X|b''\rangle \sum_{a'} \langle b''|a'\rangle\langle a'|b'\rangle .$$

But $$\sum_{a'} |a'\rangle \langle a'|$$ is the identity operator, so the latter sum evaluates to $$\langle b''|b'\rangle.$$

Comment: So does this mean it only holds for finite dimensional representations where you can shuffle around the order and use the distributive law like you just did when you brought $\sum_{b,b'} \langle b'|X|b''\rangle$ out of the sum.

Comment: @Timaeus You can reorder integrals too. Anyone who tells you otherwise has never heard of a regularization function :D I'm partially kidding because of course there are cases where you *can't* reorder integrals and those cases come up in real physica problems and are important and interesting

Comment: @DanielSank Fubuni's Theorem has hypotheses and my point is that a proof that acts like it works only in finite dimensions doesn't even indicate to the reader whether the result also holds in infinite dimensional cases.  Practically, all the physics for any particular situation is close to its projection into some finite dimensional space, so its not going to matter. But you still have to be careful with how you manipulate expressions. And it's the opposite of warning people to be careful to act like limits can always be taken in any order.

Comment: @Timaeus: The usual separable Hilbert spaces have countable bases. Given that all sums converge absolutely (which they must for the trace to exist in the first place; anyone concerned with the infinte-dimensional nature here must first define [trace-class operators](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trace_class)), the manipulations done here are fine.

Comment: @ACuriousMind My comment was based on the fact that I thought the *answer* should *indicate* whether the result holds for infinite dimensional cases, especially when the notation makes it look like it is using commutation of finite numbers of multiplication and distribution of finite numbers of addition and multiplication. If someone did a manipulation of a finite dimensional case and didn't mention an infinite dimensional case then I personally wouldn't assume the result even holds in the infinite dimensional case. I could be alone, but I think people should be careful.